ScrollView child layout (["alignItems"]) must be applied through the contentContainerStyle prop
Following a React Native tutorial using Tailwind (v 3.4.13) for building an Instagram clone. The code below produces the ScrollView child layout (["alignItems"]) must be applied through the contentContainerStyle prop error when I open Expo on my phone and iPad.
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import posts from '~/assets/data/posts.json';
import PostListItem from '~/src/components/PostListItem';

export default function FeedScreen() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={posts}
      className="items-center"
      renderItem={({ item }) => <PostListItem post={item} />}
      contentContainerStyle={{ gap: 10, maxWidth: 512, width: '100%' }}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    />
  );
}

However, based on the video, there are no issues for the programmer who created the tutorial when he compiles the same code. The repo at this point of the video is linked here.
PostListItem looks like this:
import { View, Image, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons, Feather, AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function PostListItem({ post }) {
  return (
    <View className="bg-white">
      {/* Header */}
      <View className="p-3 flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <Image
          source={{ uri: post.user.image_url }}
          className="w-12 aspect-square rounded-full"
        />
        <Text className="font-semibold">{post.user.username}</Text>
      </View>
      <Image source={{ uri: post.image_url }} className="w-full aspect-[4/3]" />

      {/* Icons */}
      <View className="flex-row gap-3 p-3">
        <AntDesign name="hearto" size={20} />
        <Ionicons name="chatbubble-outline" size={20} />
        <Feather name="send" size={20} />

        <Feather name="bookmark" size={20} className="ml-auto" />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

Trying the following code did not center the items:
<FlatList
  data={posts}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <PostListItem post={item} />}
  contentContainerStyle={{ 
    gap: 10, 
    maxWidth: 512, 
    width: '100%', 
    alignItems: 'center' 
  }}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
/>

Thanks in advance!
